# Converting minutes to 24 hour format android application

Tags: java, android

I need in my application to convert minutes to 24 hour formart, for example my app has a method that
return a time in minutes 260, how can I convert this time to 24 format?

thanks so much ,,

--- After upadting ----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//Inside OnCreate Method

//For Time Part#1
CaseDurationH.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                 int i = CaseDurationH.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 strH = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

                 try { 
                  intH = Integer.parseInt(strH); 
                  intHInMin=intH*60; // inH and intHInMin are a integer
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 

                } 


                 if(i==2){

                     CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);

                 }

                 if(strH.equals("hr0"))

                         {

                 CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);

                     }



                 if(strH.equals("hr1"))

                         {

                 CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);

                     }





                 if(strH.equals("hr2"))

                         {

                     CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);  

                     }


             }

             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub



             } });

//For Time Part#2
        CaseDurationM.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                 int i = CaseDurationM.getSelectedItemPosition();
                 strM = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();


                 try { 
                      intM = Integer.parseInt(strM); 

                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 

                    } 





             }

             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub



             } });

  String CaseTime= calc();
  case1.setTime(CaseTime); //case1 is an Onbject 



//Out OnCreate Method
private String calc() {

                      int CTimeTotalInMin= intHInMin + intM;
          Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

          int CurrentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
          int CurrentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
          int CurrentTime= (CurrentHour * 60)+ CurrentMinute;
          int TotalTimeInMin= CurrentTime-CTimeTotalInMin;
          int hours = TotalTimeInMin / 60; 
          int minutes = TotalTimeInMin % 60;  
          if(hours>23) 
             hours = hours % 24; 

       String g = ""+hours+":"+minutes;



         return g;}
```

---

my problem is: How can I  get the (current Time - the time selected by the user from the Spinner 
(I show the user two lists for hours ( 0h or 1h or 2h) and Minutes ( from 0-59) as shown below,
for instant, if the user select (1 hour ) and the current time is (2:15 PM) the answer should be= 13:15 PM), I tried this code but it couldn't differ from PM and AM ?
any Suggestion ? thanks alot...

```
<!-- @ string.xml these imtes for CDurationH= hours -->
    <string name="hr0">0</string>  
    <string name="hr1">1</string>  
    <string name="hr2">2</string> 
<!-- @ string.xml these imtes for CDurationM= minutes --> 
    <string name="min0">0</string> 
    <string name="min5">5</string> 
    <string name="min10">10</string>  
    <string name="min15">15</string> 
    <string name="min20">20</string>  
    <string name="min25">25</string>  
    <string name="min30">30</string> 
    <string name="min35">35</string>  
    <string name="min40">40</string>  
    <string name="min45">45</string> 
    <string name="min50">50</string>  
    <string name="min55">55</string>  
    <string name="min59">59</string>
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate hour and minute values via division and modulus operators.
Check for possible hour values greater than 23 indicating exceed of a daytime.
Format your values to represent as 24 hour format:

```
int minutes = 260;
int hours = minutes / 60;
int minutesInDisplay = minutes % 60;
if (hours > 23)
    hours = hours % 24;
String postfix = (hours < 12) ? "am" : "pm";
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
String display = formatter.format(hours) + ":"
        + formatter.format(minutesInDisplay);
System.out.println("24 hour formatted time: " + display + " " + postfix);
```

Comment: thanks again but I still have problem as I mention in my updated question,

Comment: thanks for your answer and responses, but i still have problem: how can i determine if it AM or PM because sometimes it'll retrieve -1:40 :" that's why i didn't upvote it, because i still have problem !

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper since it is 24 hours format, you can determine am pm easily. if hour is below 12 it is am, if it is higher than or equal to 12 it is pm. ok?

Comment: Did you see my code after updating ?
my problem the current time in 12 format (emulator time) ! 
when i test my app now, my current time is: 19:21  but it retreives 7:21 pm :|

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8591/discussion-between-android-developer-and-deporter)

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper did you apply what i told?

Comment: Thanks God my problem has been solved after using this code :

 int CurrentHour= calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

Answer (score 0):

As you know, an hour is 60 minutes. So you can just divide the number of minutes by 60 which gives you the number of hours.

```
int x = 260;

int hours = x / 60;
int minutes = x % 60;

System.out.printf("%d minutes is %d hours and %d minutes%n", x, hours, minutes);
```

If you also want the number of days:

```
int x = 2270; // just an example

// 24 * 60 = 1440 minutes in a day
int days = x / 1440;

int minutesRestInDay = x % 1440;

int hours = minutesRestInDay / 60;
int minutes = minutesRestInDay % 60;

System.out.printf("%d minutes is %d days, %d hours and %d minutes%n",
    x, days, hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getTime(int minutes){
  String value = "";
  if(minutes<=0){
    return "minutes cannot be zero or negative";
  }
  int hr=minutes/60;
  int min=minutes%60;
  if(hr>23){
    hr = hr % 24;
  }
  return  hr+":"+min;


}
```

Comment: if hr > 23 you should still return a valid hour. check it.